# how to localise a sharepoint site for different languages

Tags: sharepoint

How can i localise a sharepoint site.
i need it to copy any new content created in an english site to be copied into a german site. the actual translation is handled ok. i just need the creation of site/subites/content/pages to be copied from the english site to the german site

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a MOSS publishing site?  If so you might want to look into [variations](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101212991033.aspx).